# Distinct Object Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i distinct same object data value using Javascript? [ES15/ES16]

for the given data value

```
[{Zone: "2"},
{Zone: "4"},
{Zone: "4"},
{Zone: "6"},
{Zone: "1"},
{Zone: "2"},
{Zone: "3"},
{Zone: "3"},
{Zone: "4"},
{Zone: "4"}]
```

after it will distinct it will return

```
[{Zone: "1"},
 {Zone: "2"},
 {Zone: "2"},
 {Zone: "3"},
 {Zone: "4"},
 {Zone: "6"}]
```

Comment: the expected result is not unique

Comment: why are there 2 `{Zone: '2'}`?

Comment: is the order important to you ?

Comment: not necessary as long as it is distinct.

Comment: @guijob it was typo error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```js
var arr = [{Zone: "2"}, {Zone: "4"}, {Zone: "4"}, {Zone: "6"}, {Zone: "1"}, {Zone: "2"}, {Zone: "3"}, {Zone: "3"}, {Zone: "4"}, {Zone: "4"}]

var resp = [...new Set(arr.map(({ Zone }) => Zone))].sort().map(x => ({Zone: x}));
console.log(resp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

For this new approach you can `map` our `resp` above, using `filter` by `Zones` in your original array, as:

```js
var arr = [{Zone: "2" , Assign: "1"}, {Zone: "4", Assign: "2"}, {Zone: "4", Assign: "3"}, {Zone: "6", Assign: "4"}, {Zone: "1", Assign: "5"}, {Zone: "2", Assign: "6"}, {Zone: "3", Assign: "7"}, {Zone: "3", Assign: "8"}, {Zone: "4", Assign: "9"}, {Zone: "4", Assign: "10"}]

var resp = [...new Set(arr.map(({ Zone }) => Zone))].sort().map(x => ({Zone: x}));

var newresp = resp.map(({ Zone }) => {
  var assigns = arr.filter(x => x.Zone == Zone).map(x => x.Assign);
  return {
    Zone: Zone,
    Assign: assigns
  }
})
console.log(newresp)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks @guijob this works fine :)

Comment: One last thing sir, what if i got some additional object value. like {Zone: "2", Assign: 1} how can i also return the "Assign: 1" value?

Comment: it depends, for every `zone: 2`, will `assign: 1`?

Comment: nope it should pass to zone for every zone that is equal to it. if the object has same zone but different in assign it will return to `[{zone:2, assignnumber: [assign: 1, assign: 2] }]` ... its like re creating new object and pass the value to it.

Comment: Sorry for this, it is already out of my questions but it will really help me understand how objects works and to manipulate them.. many thanks in advance sir :)

Comment: No prob, I'm here to learn as well. I've just edited my post covering this new problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var lookup = {};
var items = [{Zone: "2"},
{Zone: "4"},
{Zone: "4"},
{Zone: "6"},
{Zone: "1"},
{Zone: "2"},
{Zone: "3"},
{Zone: "3"},
{Zone: "4"},
{Zone: "4"}];
var result = [];

for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
  var zone = item.Zone;

  if (!(zone in lookup)) {
    lookup[zone] = 1;
    result.push(zone);
  }
}
```